# MFMailComposeController

Tags: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i m trying to implement MFMailViewComposeViewController... but getting some following error plz tell why this is happing.. i am new to iPhone...

Line Location Tool:0: ".objc_class_name_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
Line Location Tool:0: symbol(s) not found
Line Location Tool:0: literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@MFMailComposeViewController in FriendShoppingListViewController.o

thanks in advance if possible provide the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import MessageUI.framework to your project to make MFMailViewComposeViewController work.